# How to find the third smallest integer?

Tags: c++

I have an array of an unknown size and would like to find the third smallest integer without sorting, how can I do this?

This was my attempt, but I couldn't get it to work.

```
int getThirdSmallest(int* arr, int size) {
    int first = arr[0];
    int second = 0;
    int third = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i > size; i++) {
        if (first > arr[i]) {
            third = second;
            second = first;
            first = arr[i];
        } else if (second > arr[i]) {
            third = second;
            second = arr[i];
        }
        else if (third > arr[i]) {
            third = arr[i];
        }
    }

    return third;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: in the for loop you have a `>` when it should have been `<`

Comment: You should initialize `second` and `third` with a large value, not with `0`,

Comment: Are you sure your array is having more than 2 elements and its getting passed to the function??

Comment: Thank you all for the help. I fixed it! I took @Rodolfo and @Henrik 's advice. I set `second = arr[size -1]` and `third = second`, fixed the `<` and initialized the loop counter at `1` instead of `0`.

Answer (score 4):

```
std::nth_element(arr, arr + 2, arr + size);
return arr[2];
```

Comment: this uses sorting, he is not supposed to sort

Comment: @Ankit It does only the minimal amount of sorting necessary to find the answer - it identifies the third smallest, and the two smaller than it (but not in any particular order). And it takes O(N) time which is faster than sorting.

Comment: @AnkitAcharya: OP would have use correct constness to express that it don't want to modify `arr` content with `int getThirdSmallest(const int* arr, int size)`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of fixing your problem, let me suggest a better way to tackle this issue. You can do it using a max-heap of size 3. The algorithm would look as follows:

- Create a Max-heap from the first 3 characters in the array.
- If the element being considered is smaller than the top element of the heap, pop the top element and insert this element.
- If the element is larger than the top element of the heap, move on to the next element.
- When you are done with all elements, the top element will be the third smallest element.

Time Complexity: O(N)

Comment: But that's sort of what the OP is trying to do, isn't it? At least, from the algorithmic point of view.

Comment: @FreeNickname : Yes, he is. However, his algorithm won't scale to `kth` smallest integer. So thinking in the manner I have said should be better for him.

Comment: Oh, now I see what you mean.